# ZK Framework: Load xls into ZK Spreadseet from Servlet

Tags: java, zk

Looking for how to load xls using servlet and set this xls into a spreadsheet.
I can't wire spreadsheet into servlet as it always null. Also, I can't get bean EventComposer using

`EventComposer loadFileServlet = (EventComposer)SpringUtil.getBean("eventComposer");`

Somehow I need to take a spreadsheet inside servlet and pass xls into it.

**Or simply saying: how to get Speradseet from Composer (jsp) in servlet**

I have jsp file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <title>zk</title>
        <zssjsp:head/>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div width="100%" style="height: 100%;">
        <zssjsp:spreadsheet id="ss" src="/WEB-INF/books/hide.xlsx" apply="org.autto.zk.EventComposer"
                            width="100%" height="100%" maxVisibleRows="200" maxVisibleColumns="40"
                            showToolbar="true" showFormulabar="true" showContextMenu="true" showSheetbar="true"/>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

EventComposer with Spreadsheet

```
public class EventComposer extends SelectorComposer<Component> {
   **********
    @Wire
    private Spreadsheet ss;

   //for testing, check xls loaded into spreadsheet after stop editing
    @Listen("onStopEditing = #ss")
    public void showBook() throws IOException {
        Path path = Paths.get("D:\\Documents\\zssjspdemo-master\\src\\main\\webapp\\upload\\blank.xls");
        File file = path.toFile();

        Importer importer = Importers.getImporter();
        Book book =  importer.imports(getStreamData(file), "hide");
        ss.setBook(book);
    }
    ********

}
```

Also have servlet

```
@WebServlet("/load")
public class LoadFileServlet extends HttpServlet {
     @Wire
    private Spreadsheet ss; // this spreadsheet null, can't wire it

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(req);
        if (!isMultipart) {
            resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
            return;
        }

        DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

        factory.setSizeThreshold(1024 * 1024);

        File tempDir = (File)getServletContext().getAttribute("javax.servlet.context.tempdir");
        factory.setRepository(tempDir);

        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

        upload.setSizeMax(1024 * 1024 * 10);

        try {
            List items = upload.parseRequest(req);
            Iterator iter = items.iterator();

            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                FileItem item = (FileItem)iter.next();

                if (item.isFormField()) {
                    processFormField(item);
                } else {
                    processUploadedFile(item);



                  **//whant to do something like this but ss is null
                  Importer importer = Importers.getImporter();
                  Book book = importer.imports(getStreamData(item), "hide");
                  ss.setBook(book);**

                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            return;
        }
    }

    /**
     * save file to upload folder.
     * folder should be created already
     *
     * @param item
     * @throws Exception
     */
    private void processUploadedFile(FileItem item) throws Exception {
        File uploadedFile = null;
        do {
            String path = getServletContext().getRealPath("/upload/" + item.getName());
            uploadedFile = new File(path);
        } while (uploadedFile.exists());

        uploadedFile.createNewFile();
        item.write(uploadedFile);
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.zkoss.zss</groupId>
    <artifactId>home</artifactId>
    <version>3.9.5-Eval</version>
    <properties>
        <commons-io>1.3.1</commons-io>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd</maven.build.timestamp.format>
        <packname>-${project.version}-FL-${maven.build.timestamp}</packname>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>The zssjsp demo Project</name>
    <description>The zssjspdemo Project</description>
    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>GNU LESSER GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE, Version 3</name>
            <url>http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html</url>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
        </license>
    </licenses>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>ZK CE</id>
            <name>ZK CE Repository</name>
            <url>http://mavensync.zkoss.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>ZK EVAL</id>
            <name>ZK Evaluation Repository</name>
            <url>http://mavensync.zkoss.org/eval</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>  
            <id>prime-repo</id>  
            <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>  
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>  
            <layout>default</layout>  
        </repository>  
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>zkmaven</id>
            <name>ZK Maven Plugin Repository</name>
            <url>http://mavensync.zkoss.org/maven2/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-io}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zkoss.zss</groupId>
            <artifactId>zssex</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zkoss.zss</groupId>
            <artifactId>zssjsp</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.11.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.11.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Jackson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.9/httpclient-4.5.9.jar -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>25.0.0.redhat-1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.2.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Run with Jetty -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>6.1.10</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>5</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <stopKey>foo</stopKey>
                    <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
                    <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**UPD 1:**
Thanks to Hawk for the idea:
How it works now:
1. Added processShowBook(item, req, resp); to the request:

```
    private void processShowBook(FileItem item, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws IOException, ServletException {
    request.setAttribute("string", getPathString(item));
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request,response);
}
```

2. Added to the composer

   ```
   public void doAfterCompose(Component comp) throws Exception {
   super.doAfterCompose(comp);
   String  s = (String)((HttpServletRequest)Executions.getCurrent().getNativeRequest()).getAttribute("string");
   if (s != null) {
       showBook(s);
   }
   ```

   }

   ```
   public void showBook(String s) throws IOException {
   Path path = Paths.get(s);
   File file = path.toFile();

   Importer importer = Importers.getImporter();
   Book book = importer.imports(getStreamData(file), "hide");
   ss.setBook(book);
   ```

   }

I've tried two variants from section pass via Request
In both way I have book, or string Path.
Spreadsheet also available but not updated. Why?

from another side if I add @Listen("onStopEditing = #ss")
to the showBook method, and pass Path string, edit exl and prees enter, spreadsheet is updated.

**UPD 2:**
The problem is that when ss is loaded it has id 8418 (example.)
when I send request, and call doAfterCompose id is 8452.
when I edit cell and triger onCellSelection id again 8418.
And have different Sessions.

As I undarstand when servlet redirect request to index.jsp/zul , I create new object ss while calling doAfterCompose, but still have old active ss. How can I avoid this?

[what I have when send request inside do aftercompose()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flgNU.gif)

[when I select cell on the same window without reloading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uaf7I.gif)

Comment: I have send you a pull request to your repo ihorkazakov/zssjspdemo. Please merge it and visit form.jsp, upload a file, it should display in ZSS correctly.

Comment: thanks this solution works fine.

But in this case, I'm looking for a little bit another behavior:
as it's a part of another app, ss should be updated after post request with xls file. without any additional forms.

so I should send .xls using POST request (for example using postman) and ss should load this .xls.

Comment: form.jsp is just a way to test `LoadFileServlet`. If we can make `LoadFileServlet` to `Composer` work correctly. Then, it doesn't matter that where does the POST request come from (a form or another app).

Comment: I just show you how to connect a servlet with ZSS, and you can keep developing based on this.

Comment: thanks for that. I understand that it should work, but interesting why when I send a POST with file my spreadsheet not load it.

Comment: and another thing: for example, I open xls using the form and it opened, and next time I send xls using POST request, but ss not reloaded with new xls.

Comment: It's better to set a breakpoint (or print a log) in your composer to check it receives the expected parameter. If you still can't find the root cause, it's better for us to check with an online meeting. what's your timezone?

Answer (score 0):

## the reason it failed

ZK composer lives in a specific "Desktop" scope, created by ZK, which is shorter than a session but longer than a request. Each time you load (or reload) a page with a ZK component, a server creates a new component and a new composer, and wire the components on the page into the composer, then the component renders a javascript widget to your browser. The rendered javascript widget and java component form a pair. When you interactive with the widget, it fires AJAX requests to the server instead of reloading the whole page. 
​
ZK has its process to control the lifecycle of a composer,  the composer you created by your own like new EventComposer() is not the same one that created by ZK framework.

There are 3 approaches I recommend:

## include ZUL approach

Because the zul provides richer feature,  you can just implement the upload feature with FileUpload component in a zul. So it's easier to communicate between 2 zk components (FileUpload and Spreadsheet) in the same page. Then you just need to include the zul in jsp like jsp menu example. 
For how to implement upload, please refer to File Upload in Dev Reference

## pass via Request

You can implement upload by your current servlet way.
1. store the Book object (produced by Importer) as a `HttpServletRequest` attribute.
2. forward the request (keep the request unchanged) to the JSP with a spreadsheet
3. get the Book in your `Composer.doAfterCompose()` 
`((HttpServletRequest)Excuctions.getCurrent().getNativeRequest()).getAttribute()`

Another way is:
1. directly store the xls file in a specific folder 
2. pass the file name as a query string
3. forward the request to the JSP with a spreadsheet
4. get the query string (file name by HttpServletRequest.getParameter()
5. import the file

Check [this example](https://github.com/zkoss/zssjspdemo/blob/master/src/main/java/org/zkoss/zss/jspdemo/FileLoadServlet.java) which is simple but shows the idea.

## `@Wire` doesn't work in a Servlet

`@Wire` is a ZK annotation, which only works in ZK`SelectorComposer`

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I've added to the post UPD, with the result.
Shortly:
tried two ideas with pass via Request, have o book or string with Path inside composer,
but the spreadsheet not updated. 
Wondering why.

Comment: Also, I tried Zul approach from the very beginning, and it worked fine, but I need to send .xls using Http POST

Comment: Also tried get Spreadhseet from Executions.getCurrent().getDesktop().getComponents()
But have the same result - speadssheet not updated.

Comment: Also tried, 
1.change jsp to zul. 
2. put spreadsheet into window, 
3. Add window to composer, and on last step added  window.appendChild(ss);
but have the same result - ss not updated.

Comment: The problem is that when ss is loaded it has id 8418 (example.)
when I send request, and call doAfterCompose id is 8452.
when I edit cell and triger onCellSelection id again 8418.
So I have different ss. As I undarstand when servlet redirect request to index.jsp/zu , I create new object ss while calling doAfterCompose. How can I avoid this?

Comment: One of the idea:
as I see in this example I have two threads, one when spreadsheet initialized and one when I call redirect inside a servlet and again initialize spreadsheet, in both of them I have a different spreadsheet.
Somehow I need to pass the Path or File from servlet to exactly first thread. 
Am I right?

Comment: You should just forward (not redirect) the request with the file information (string/file stream), and let ZK framework initialize the composer and ZSS component. You should not call `doAfterCompose()` by yourself. If you see 2 different spreadsheet object, then it is probably wrong.

Comment: For each redirect/reload a page, ZK starts a page loading life cycle, and it will create new desktop, new composer, and new components. This is architectural behavior that you can't avoid. When you edit cells, ZSS fires an event with AJAX requests, such an HTTP request doesn't reload the whole page which is different from the previous page loading request. For such AJAX request, ZK doesn't create new Desktop/Composer/Component.

Comment: What I'm doing wrong? 
in servlet I forward the request : request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request,response);
After that doAfterCompose() call automatically inside  eventcomposer. 
I added this code snipet in UPD section above.

Comment: saw your git. Inside MyComposer.java you've done the same thing as me.
But after I forward request, as I described I have another spreadsheet when doAfterCompose invoced.